# Can I pickle a string without any dump?

Tags: python, pickle

Say I have a string "[A,B,C]" and I want to convert it into a list [A,B,C], I have googled around and I know I should use pickle, but it seems that before I `pickle.loads` I seems to have to  `pickle.dumps` the object, is that true? If yes, how can I walk around this?

Answer (score 2):

`pickle.dumps` is the function that serializes Python objects into Pickle strings, and `pickle.loads` converts serialized Pickle strings into Python objects. You're basically asking how to deserialize an object which isn't serialized. The answer is that you can't.

However, bikeshredder is correct -- your string is already in JSON's serialization format, so you can use `json.loads`.

Comment: But if I use json it gives me something like [u'A',u'B',...] is this because my data file is encoded as utf-8 so u here stands for the encoding?

Comment: @dorafmon Can you post your code? That looks like Python's string format, not JSON.

Comment: `json.loads(self.graphroot.find(".//node[@key=\""+str(vertex.key)+"\"]")[0].text)` I am using elementTree to read in some xml file and then using json.loads to convert the text of an element into a list.

Comment: @dorafmon Oh, then yeah it's fine. If you `print` a list of strings you got from `json`, it will put the "u" in front of them to indicate that it's unicode. This behavior is because of how `print` works, not because of JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The string "[A,B,C]" is neither a pickle format nor any other serialization format known to me. It is not Python code either.

If you just want to deserialize some data (e.g. read from a file) I would recommend to use [JSON](http://json.org/). It is easy to write, fast to parse and is a well established standard.

```
>>> import json
>>> data_json = '["A", "B", "C"]'
>>> data = json.loads(data_json)
>>> data
[u'A', u'B', u'C']
>>> data_json = json.dumps(data)
>>> data_json
'["A", "B", "C"]'
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, thanks! I am so stupid! I should double quote A B and C.

Comment: But it gives me something like [u'A',u'B'...], why is that the case?

Comment: `u'foo'` and `u"foo"` are two different representation for the same string. The `u` in front of the string shows that this is a `unicode` string and not just a `bytestring`. JSON uses UTF-8 encoding and the correct representation of a JSON string is a Python unicode string. Unicode strings can even be compared to normal strings without any special syntax if they only contain ASCII. `u'foo' == 'foo'` is `True`.

Comment: @bikeshedder thanks, can I specify the encoding of my python source code to be also UTF-8?

Comment: Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to your source files. When specifying unicode strings in your source you should also quote them using `u''`. btw. Python 3 uses UTF-8 by default and strings without prefix are unicode and strings with a `b` prefix are bytestrings. I was silently assuming that you were using Python 2.